# I am trying to consume a webservice through jquery but it throws this error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: jquery, web-services

I am trying to consume a webservice through jquery but it throws this error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response
>   had HTTP status code 500.

I read that it's related about "cross domain" but I can't resolve it.

My code looks like this:

```
    <script src="js/jquery.soap.js"></script>

    <script>


        console.log("Entering processPeticion...");    

        // OBTENGO EL BARRIO A PARTIR DE LATITUD Y LONGITUD             
        var wsUrl = "http://gisdesa.mardelplata.gob.ar/opendata/ws.php/latlong_barrio";

        var soapRequest =
            '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:open="http://192.168.0.235/opendata"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><open:latlong_barrio soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><latitud xsi:type="xsd:string">-38.001095</latitud><longitud xsi:type="xsd:string">-57.551533</longitud><token xsi:type="xsd:string">wwfe345gQ3ed5T67g4Dase45F6fer</token></open:latlong_barrio></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",                    
                url: wsUrl,
                contentType: "text/xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: soapRequest,
                success: processSuccess,
                error: processError
        });

       function processSuccess(data, status, req) {


            console.log("Entering processPeticion.success()...");

            var barrioCodigo;
            var barrioDescripcion;

            var myObj = new Array();

            if (status == "success"){

                barrioCodigo = $(req.responseXML)
                .find("latlong_barrioResponse")
                .find("return")
                .find("codigo").text();
                console.log(barrioCodigo);    

                barrioDescripcion = $(req.responseXML)
                .find("latlong_barrioResponse")
                .find("return")
                .find("descripcion").text();
                console.log(barrioDescripcion);                        

            }

        }

        function processError(data, status, req) {        

            console.log("Entering processPeticion.processError()...");

        }                 

    </script>
```

Any help?

Comment: We need more information.  For example, I' am guessing you are testing code on LOCALHOST that consumes a web service hosted on somewhere.somplace.com...and somewhere.somplace.com is *not* configured to allow requests from other domains - hence the cross domain 500.

Answer (score 0):

try this request

$.ajax({

```
  type: "POST",                    
  url: wsUrl,
  contentType: "text/xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  crossDomain: true,
  data: soapRequest,
  success: processSuccess,
  error: processError
});
```

Comment: doesn't function... :-(

Comment: you can looking then on this http://forum.rejectedsoftware.com/groups/rejectedsoftware.vibed/thread/10500/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754489/access-control-allow-origin-and-angular-js-http

Comment: Problem solved! You must to have a `<!doctype html>` of the top of your HTML page ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call a SOAP web service from client side code, which is almost always a bad idea. Most webservice implementations never return the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and as result you will never be able to call these webservices from client side code because of the browser's [CORS Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). If your app has a server side backend, consider implementing a call to the third party web service on the server and passing the response via JSON to your front end.

Comment: Are you getting this error in your desktop browser emulator? Or on device too? Phonegap apps do not need have CORS restrictions so you would get this error only in a real web-browser. Have you tested on device? For this to work in a real web browser the web service needs to be CORS enabled, no way around it.

Comment: I have tested on device and doesn't function. I have an example that function in Chrome and doesn't function on the device. Any help?